# Z-index problem with ie7 ... working in firefox. Images showing behind other img's

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, html-lists

I need some help figuring out a solution to a z-index problem with ie7.  Works fine in firefox.

I've read other posts, but for some reason the suggestions that worked for them are not working for me.  I'm hoping someone can look at my code and point out where the problem is.

See the image below.  please excuse the blurr...client doesn't want info displayed.

The top section (grey) is a "div" with 2 ul's in it, one for the bullet text, one fir the image thumbnails.  The bottom section is identical to the top, only its colored white.

In the top section I have 3 images, when "hovered" over with mouse display a larger image.  As you can see, the larger image is behind the next section (white) images and it should be on top of it.

I'm assuming the problem is somewhere in the jquery z-index, but I really don't know.

How can I fix this? Thanks for your help.

[image]

HTML:

```
<body>
<div style="position:relative;width:1000px;">
<!-- Main Content -->
    <h2 class="h2_pad_me">Feature Details</h2>

    <div class="light pad_me">
        <h3>asdf</h3>
        <p>asdf</p> 
        <ul>
            <li>asdf</li>
            <li>asdf</li>
            <li>asdf</li>
        </ul>
        <h4>asdf:</h4>
        <div>
            <ul class="thumb_standard">
                <li><img src="asdf.jpg" alt="asdf"/></li>
                <li><img src="asdf.jpg" alt="asdf"/></li>
                <li><img src="asdf.jpg" alt="asdf"/></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="clear_both"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="light pad_me">
        <h3>asdf</h3>
        <p>asdf</p> 
        <ul>
            <li>asdf</li>
            <li>asdf</li>
            <li>asdf</li>
        </ul>
        <h4>asdf:</h4>
        <div>
            <ul class="thumb_standard">
                <li><img src="asdf.jpg" alt="asdf"/></li>
                <li><img src="asdf.jpg" alt="asdf"/></li>
                <li><img src="asdf.jpg" alt="asdf"/></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="clear_both"></div>
    </div>
</div>                      

</body>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
ul.thumb_standard {
    /*float: left;*/
    list-style: none;
    margin: auto; 
    padding: 10px;
    width: 900px;
    position:relative;
}
ul.thumb_standard li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;    
    float: left;
    width: 210px;
    height: 110px;
    position: relative;
    z-index:-1
}

ul.thumb_standard li img {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; /* IE Fix for Bicubic Scaling */
}
.clear_both{clear:both;}
.light{ background-color:#FFFFFF;}
.pad_me{padding:5px 15px 0px 15px;}

</style>
```

Jquery for the animated popup:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $("ul.thumb_standard li").hover(function() {
            $(this).css({'z-index' : '1000'}); /*Add a higher z-index value so this image stays on top*/ 
            var li = $(this);
            var img = li.find('img');
            var div = li.closest('div');

            // Add hover class and stop animation
            li.addClass('hover');
            img.stop(); /* Stop animation queue buildup*/

            // Find the position relative to the div
            var new_width = 700;
            var new_height = 500;
            var new_left = (div.width() - new_width) / 2;
            var new_top = (div.height() - new_height) / 2;

            // Find the position relative to the li
            var li_offset = li.position();
            new_left -= li_offset.left;
            new_top -= li_offset.top;

            img.animate({                                   
                    top: '-100%',
                    left: new_left + 'px',
                    width: new_width + 'px',
                    height: new_height + 'px'
                }, 200); /* this value of "200" is the speed of how fast/slow this hover animates */

        } , function() {
            $(this).css({'z-index' : '-1'}); /*set z-index value back*/ 
            var li = $(this);
            var img = $(this).find('img');
            var div = $(this).parent('div');

            // Remove hover class and stop animation
            li.removeClass("hover");
            img.stop(); /* Stop animation queue buildup*/

            var new_width = 210;
            var new_height = 110;

            img.animate({
                    top: '0px',
                    left: '0px',
                    width: new_width + 'px',
                    height: new_height + 'px'
                }, 400); /* this value of "400" is the speed of how fast/slow this hover animates */
        }); //Closes .hover()
    }); //Closes .document()
</script>
```

Comment: @rone , where is your container ,or parent holder for high resolution image popup , give z-index like some 100 to that.

Comment: sorry, I had to step away...I'm back now.  The hi res img container is the img itself. In css I set the width/height so the img is smaller and looks like a thumbnail, but on the jquery hover event I set the width/height to the original img size so it appears like a popup.  I'll look at the z-index in the jquery code because I'm thinking its on the "li" and not the img?

Comment: @if you put on the parent holder thats fine.

Comment: I've tried it everywhere...I'm getting the same results in ie, but firefox great.  I put z-index 1000 on the img, the li, ul, div, and parent div...all those elements have position:relative.  i'm stuck

Comment: @rone , then there is some other problem , can you attach a better screenshot of your probem in IE..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never could figure this out...had to make the pictures smaller and the problem didn't show up anymore.

Answer (score 0):

z-index takes precedence in the order you give , for example if you have a div with z-index 1 and a popup div with z-index 0 , the popup will go behind and looks bad, so you have give z-index higher than 1 which is 2 or 4 anything , so it takes higher precedence.

So for the popup images or div which is hold that , give a higher z-index like 100 or 200 anything higher than existing one...

it will fix the problem.

```
http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_z-index.asp
```

read the above link , its really useful

one more thing , i don't think this is right in your code

```
$(this).css({'z-index' : '1000'}); /
```

change to

```
$(this).css('z-index','1000');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply...I tried your suggestions, but get the same results

Comment: both versions of the JS here are correct, you can use the top one to apply more than one item of style like so: $(this).css({'display': 'block', 'position': 'relative'});